# How to release connection in jbpm

Tags: java, rest, jbpm, httpconnection

I have created the  custom REST api that calls the JBPM Apis.
Whenever an API is called ,

```
SELECT * FROM (select vil.processinstanceid, vil.processid, vil.id, vil.variableid, vil.value from variableinstancelog vil where vil.id in (select max(v.id) from variableinstancelog v group by v.variableid, v.processinstanceid)) AS "dbSQL" LIMIT 1
```

This query occupies the connection and not releasing the connection.
Due to this number of  connections increased and lastly database down.
NOTE:I am not calling this query anywhere but jbpm does internally.
Can anyone tells how can I release connection ?Do I need to set anything in Configuration file ?